# Заключение в кавычки пьесы с жанровым названием и порядковым номером

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, названия

*Отсылаю вам работу по инструментовке 10 мимолётность Прокофьева.*

Грамотно ли оформлено предложение? Требует ли "10 мимолётность" заключения в кавычки? Довольно спорным вопросом является выделение мимолётности в самостоятельный жанр, однако всё-таки его рассматривают как жанр (иногда называя синонимом других жанров).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Порядковые числительные должны иметь буквенные наращения: 1-й, 2-му, 10-я и пр.

Если уж и оставлять предложение в первоначальном виде, то так: *Отсылаю вам работу по инструментовке 10-й мимолётности Прокофьева*. Но выделение мимолётности в самостоятельный жанр, как Вы говорите, спорный вопрос, и пока такое определение не принято, [«Мимолётности»](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) являются названием цикла произведений (пьес), поэтому их нужно писать с прописной буквы в кавычках и относить к жанру миниатюр. Встретилось такое обозначение отдельных частей: [«Мимолётность» № 10](http://music-fantasy.ru/materials/sergey-prokofev-v-kazhdoy-mimolyotnosti-vizhu-ya-miry).

Возможные варианты:

*Отсылаю вам работу по инструментовке 10-й пьесы из «Мимолётностей» Прокофьева* (или *...из сборника «Мимолётности»...* или просто: *10-й «Мимолётности»*).

*Отсылаю вам работу по инструментовке «Мимолётности» № 10 Прокофьева.*

P. S. Владимир, кажется, я понял Ваш комментарий по поводу согласования в падеже. Тогда необходим знак препинания (двоеточие, тире или запятая). *Отсылаю вам работу по инструментовке: 10-ю "Мимолётность" Прокофьева.* Номер можно написать и словом: десятую.

Comment: Обязательны ли наращения? Разве наращения не факультативны? И я хотел согласовать в падеже слова "работу" и "10-ю".

Comment: @ВладимирЖеребцов   Согласование в падежах следующее: работу  (какую?, по чему?) по инструментовке (чего?) "Мимолетности" (какой?) 10-й или № 10.

Comment: @ВладимирЖеребцов О факультативности наращений не слышал, без него числительное читается как десять. О наращениях можно посмотреть здесь:   http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99

Comment: @ВладимирЖеребцов  Если ответ Вам помог, отметьте его стрелочкой вверх и галочкой слева. Если остались еще вопросы по структуре предложения, спрашивайте, постараюсь ответить. Спасибо за вопрос!

Comment: Нет, всё ясно, спасибо!